# atom text-editor - Ao clicar na função ir para o código

Tags: php, atom

O Netbeans tem a função nativo já, quero que, no atom, ao clicar em cima da função segundo ctrl mais clique, vá para a função seja outro arquivo ou no mesmo.

Sei que tem como mas não sei fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora o Atom virou **Atom IDE** graças ao [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/), uma comunidade bem ativa e potente adotada pelo Facebook. Agora o que era apenas um editor, acabouse transformando em uma verdadeira IDE.

Eu consegui fazer o que você está solicitando, pois isso, eu uso bastante no PHPstorm e no Eclipse... :)

Para fazer o seu Atom Editor se transformar em uma IDE oficial, é muito fácil. Vem comigo e siga os passos abaixo:

Instale o pacote [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui)
Instale o seu pacote de linguagem favorita. Neste caso, o PHP: [ide-php](https://github.com/atom/ide-php/)
Eu escrevi um artigo fazendo um review e um comentário mais bacana da ferramenta do Atom IDE. [Acesse este link para obter mais informações](http://binariux.com.br/seja-bem-vindo-ao-atom-ide/).

Comment: Muito bom Thiago Cunha.... instalei o atom-ide-ui e foi habilitado o hiperlink para a função desejada, como tem no Netbeans entre outras IDE's.

Answer (score 1):

`preferredLineLength` tem a ver com tamanho de colunas na linha e não ir ao código fonte com ctrl+click. Você precisa instalar um plugin que te de essa funcionalidade. Para PHP tem esse aqui https://atom.io/packages/atom-autocomplete-php.